# What are the spectral indices that use addition of Landsat 8 bands for finding vegetation?

Tags: raster, landsat, ndvi, vegetation-index

NDVI is found out using the division of subtraction and addition of bands. Is there a simpler index for finding out vegetation(or other physical characteristic)? For example, DVI=NearInfraRed-Red is a simple linear operation for finding vegetation. There might be other such simple operations on bands for finding different physical characteristics of a region.

Comment: Try a few combinations and see what you get, there is a finite number of ways you can combine 7 bands... I don't think you can get much simpler without giving false positives/negatives.. not all vegetation has the same IR spectrum and climatic conditions radically effect the signatures. Using NDVI is at least a recognized (some would say standard) method and isn't that hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

**NDVI= (NIR-RED) / (NIR+RED)**

Found this which may help - http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/broadbandgreenness.html

Other resources which may be useful -

1. https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/24/band-combinations-for-landsat-8/

Band Combinations for Landsat 8
by kevin_butler on July 24, 2013
 1763 208 50K
Landsat 8 has been online for a couple of months now, and the images look incredible. While all of the bands from previous Landsat missions are still incorporated, there are a couple of new ones, such as the coastal blue band water penetration/aerosol detection and the cirrus cloud band for cloud masking and other applications. Here’s a rundown of some common band combinations applied to Landsat 8, displayed as a red, green, blue (RGB):

Natural Color   4 3 2
False Color (urban) 7 6 4
Color Infrared (vegetation) 5 4 3
Agriculture 6 5 2
Atmospheric Penetration 7 6 5
Healthy Vegetation  5 6 2
Land/Water  5 6 4
Natural With Atmospheric Removal    7 5 3
Shortwave Infrared  7 5 4
Vegetation Analysis 6 5 4

2. http://landsat.usgs.gov/best_spectral_bands_to_use.php
   Landsat 8 Operational Land Imager (OLI) and Thermal Infrared Sensor (TIRS)

Band    Wavelength  Useful for mapping
Band 1 – coastal aerosol    0.43 - 0.45 coastal and aerosol studies
Band 2 – blue   0.45 - 0.51 Bathymetric mapping, distinguishing soil from vegetation and deciduous from coniferous vegetation
Band 3 - green  0.53 - 0.59 Emphasizes peak vegetation, which is useful for assessing plant vigor
Band 4 - red    0.64 - 0.67 Discriminates vegetation slopes
Band 5 - Near Infrared (NIR)    0.85-0.88   Emphasizes biomass content and shorelines
Band 6 - Short-wave Infrared (SWIR) 1   1.57 - 1.65 Discriminates moisture content of soil and vegetation; penetrates thin clouds
Band 7 - Short-wave Infrared (SWIR) 2   2.11 - 2.29 Improved moisture content of soil and vegetation and  thin cloud penetration
Band 8 - Panchromatic   0.50 - 0.68 15 meter resolution, sharper image definition
Band 9 – Cirrus 1.36 - 1.38 Improved detection of cirrus cloud contamination
Band 10 – TIRS 1    10.60 – 11.19   100 meter resolution, thermal mapping and estimated soil moisture
Band 11 – TIRS 2    11.5 - 12.51    100 meter resolution, Improved thermal mapping and estimated soil moisture

3. http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/?page_id=5377
4. http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/Home/NewsUpdates/TabId/170/ArtMID/735/ArticleID/14305/The-Many-Band-Combinations-of-Landsat-8.aspx

All the best !

Comment: The first resource lists a whole bunch of vegetation indexes, both simple and complex. You might find something in there which fits your requirements.